# QFile not opening/finding file

Tags: c++, qt, file

I have this small file opening function, using `QFile`, but after debugging i've noticed that its skipping the function - something to do with not finding the file or a coding error?

```
QString s;
QFile file(QString::fromStdString(fileName));
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QTextStream in(&file);
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        s = in.readLine();
        shipHandler::lineParse(s);
    }
}
```

The file im trying to open is a text file, and its located in the main folder with all the other headers + source files. I'm passing `"file.txt"` to this function.

Comment: what's stored into `QString::fromStdString(fileName)`?

Comment: @Jepessen The function is passed a string, my case "Ships.txt" and I've used that to convert the it to a QString. When debugging it shows that it takes the file name, but seems to not read from it

Comment: 1 - Are you sure that it contains that name? Create a QString intermediate variable and check it. 2 - Ships.txt has no absolute folder. Whrere is stored the file and what's the working folder of your program? Try to use an absolute path name to start.

Comment: I'm not sure if as when I debug and hover over the variable name fileName, I get -> http://oi59.tinypic.com/2ymdu1g.jpg - but once it gets passed the QFile statement and I hover over that I get -> http://oi59.tinypic.com/eukgua.jpg - so im not sure as to whats going wrong

Comment: @horHAY Relative paths. Relative paths. Relative paths. Relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with `QFile` not finding the file. If the full path is not specified, QFile will look in the current directory. The current directory is: `QDir::currentPath()`

So first try if it works if you supply the complete path, if it works you will need to put the 'ships.txt' in the correct path.

What I normally do in projects is place the file in the same folder of the EXE (or in a folder in same directory as the EXE). Then retrieve the path of the EXE and use it the form an new path to the file.

For example: **(Not tested!)**

```
QString exePath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()
QString shipsPath = exePath + QDir::separator() + 'ships.txt'
```

Comment: I've just tried adding the full path but the same problem. The project folder is on my desktop, all the files including the txt file is in the project folder. When I step through the function, it gets to the if statement, then goes back up one, then to the end of the function.

Comment: Yeah just used those two lines, and its going into the file reading now. The path is also using my debug folder, which I had also placed the file in just in case! Thanks